# I Accidentally ejaculated is my fast broken?

Tags: practical-islam, sin, ramadan

Must the fast be continued or the fast is completely broken

Answer (score 0):

No. It only breaks fasts if you masturbate or look at pornography on purpose. Just know that you can't help it and you can continue fasting. (Jami` at-Tirmidhi : 719)